# How to debug CGAL generated with cmake

Tags: debugging, cmake, cgal

I would like to Step thorugh my CGAL code, because it doesn't work.
Wiht Linux I only get assembler. What do I need to do to debug it?
I have set:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g DEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g DEBUG")
set(CMAKE_DONT_OVERRIDE_CMAKE_FLAGS=True)
```

Here the beginning of my  CMakeList.txt. The rest is auto generated with `cgal_create_CMakeLists`:

```
# Created by the script cgal_create_CMakeLists
# This is the CMake script for compiling a set of CGAL applications.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1...3.23)

project( MySurfaceMesh )
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -DDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -DDEBUG")
set(DCGAL_DONT_OVERRIDE_CMAKE_FLAGS=TRUE)
# CGAL and its components
find_package( CGAL QUIET COMPONENTS  )

if ( NOT CGAL_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.")
  return()

endif()


# Boost and its components
find_package( Boost REQUIRED )
.........
```

Comment: The first line (if placed early enough and not overridden) should have done it. What doesn't work? What do you mean you only get assembler?

Comment: I set it directly under the `project` definition.
If I want to debug it with gdb I only get assebbler code for x86.
I would expect the debugging Information so that i can read the c/++ code.
Or are my expectionations wrong